# Extremely slow download, while upload works fine

Tags: networking, internet

The download speed on my Pi is somehow almost dead (working in Bytes/sec and then gets stalled). I tried downloading files through wget, download files over LAN using scp, using rsync and yet it's all the same.

While, from my laptop, if I try downloading some file FROM my Pi, it is working at full speed. Also, if I upload from Pi to laptop using `scp`, it is working fine.

I also tested my SD Card performance and it was all fine. I tested my SD Card using this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.tmp bs=500K count=1024 oflag=direct
```

What could be the possible problem?

I've looked at many other similar questions posted before. Nothing has helped so far.

**PS:** My Pi is currently at a distance of a few kilometers connected at a client using long-distance router. So, I can't access it physically right now.

### UPDATE

This problem continues to trouble. I'm adding more details.

I have setup a WiFi mesh network spanning a few kilometres, connected using Ubiquiti Routers. For the mesh, I have one base-station with a big Ubiquiti router. Several clients are connected to this base-station. On the client-side, I have a smaller Ubiquiti Router, which is providing the connection to the Raspberry Pi.

For quite some time, I has believed that the slow download speed might have been because of some wrong settings in Ubiquiti. But, in one of the clients I had installed Intel Galileo. And it is working perfectly. So now, it is sure that there is some problem in RPi itself. Can anyone guide me towards some direction as to where the fault in RPi might lie?

Also note that when I use my Pi directly with my laptop, with no Ubiquiti setup in between, then its speed is fine. So, the problem has to lie somewhere in the combination of Pi and my Ubiquiti setup.

Comment: In your first paragraph you say that the "download speed on your Pi is almost dead", but in your second paragraph you state that you are downloading from the Pi to your laptop which would indicate that you are uploading from the Pi? So which one is it?

Comment: From my laptop, I try to "download" from my Pi using `scp`. So, yes, technically it is "uploading" from my Pi. The statement is correct in my question, though confusing. Could you edit the statement for better clarity?

Comment: Okay, I've updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: So what happens when you upload files from your laptop to your Pi can you please indicate at what kind of speeds you are able to achieve?

Comment: @Mohammad : In uploading, I am achieving quite good speed (around 5 MBps), while in downloading it's in Bytes per second until the downloading just stalls.

Comment: Are we talking Downloading on the Pi or on your laptop and uploading on the Pi

Comment: Is this related to only that specific rPI at that location, or any device at that location? In other words: can you confirm the **network** is fine?

Comment: All my rPis are having exact same configuration (except IP address). And all are behaving this way. Network shouldn't be a problem, as Galileo is working fine on the same network.

Comment: Can you confirm that the Pis work fine on a different network? This would tell us if it's the Pi or the network.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for your reply, but it's been more than 3 years now, since the issue. It got resolved somehow, but I don't remember now how. The setup that I had, anyways, doesn't exist now.

Answer (score 2):

Hidden node problem:

```
noise----Pi-----AP
```

Pi hears noise AP does not.

People on the phone with you don't have a problem hearing you when your kids are screaming, but you can't hear the phone.

Relocate and test again.

`wget -O /dev/null` to eliminate disk IO from the equation.  It matters a lot!

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't have that old setup (from 5 years back!) now to troubleshoot. But will remember this for future.